# Messages won't distribute among consumers in group

Tags: apache-kafka

Just getting started with Apache Kafka (v 3.5.1), using only console for the moment.

So, I've created a topic with 3 partitions,

`kafka-topics.sh --topic t_3 --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1`

Then created three consumers in the same group:

`kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic t_3 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group group_one`

Then created producer:

`kafka-console-producer.sh --topic t_3 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

But the group isn't balanced, as it was expected. When I produce messages, they all go to one consumer. When I stop one of the consumers, messages start to go to both consumers that are left, I mean every message received by both consumers.

I thought in this case, each consumer should receive message only from its own partition, and producer must write messages to partions by round-robin. What do I do wrong?

P.S. In Kafka log I see this phrase when adding new consumer: rebalance failed due to MemberIdRequiredException. But I can't figure out, what do I do wrong, cause all the docs and answers and videos tell, that expected behaviour with default configurations is just as what I thought it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> producer must write messages to partions by round-robin

How old are the docs / videos you're seeing? StickyPartitioner was added around v2.4, which changed how records are *batched together* in a producer , and only get sent to one partition, rather than having each message being round robined. This ultimately results in less network requests being spread out over the whole cluster. From a consumer perspective, this should be transparent as all brokers should be considered equal.

If data is only produced to one partition (you could check that too), then only that assigned consumer would read that (it shouldn't go to multiple partitions without multiple batches).

In other words, consumers in a group are rarely truly "balanced" since data is only ever written to a leader partition, and that partition could have more data sent to it than others.

Comment: Maybe to add some context, you can use keyed partitioning to enable distribution of messages between partitions and thus your consumers more evenly.  Beware that doing this,  you will lose ordered messages, as Kafka only ensures partition based ordering.